# How do I convert stored hexa number array to decimal with MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I need a string array stored as an Hexa number and i need to convert it to a base 10 number (decimal).

```
.data
    inputNumberArray:   .space  32
```

This array was read using

```
la   $a0, inputNumberArray  # load inputBase address to a0
li  $v0, 8          # read_string syscall code = 8
li  $a1, 32         # space allocated for inputBase
syscall
```

So I have an array like

`inputNumberArray = 3E8`

And I need the output to be

`outputArray = 1000`

Thanks :D

Comment: How would you do it in any other language?  It often helps to write the algorithm in a high level language and then implement it in assembly based on a statement-by-statement breakdown.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/818378/547981)

Comment: I'm trying to do that, but assembly is a quite difficult to manage sometime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it working!

I have an input array like [7b] store in `inputNumberArray`

```
### HEXA -> DECIMAL
fromHexaStringToDecimal:
    # start counter
    la   $t2, inputNumberArray       # load inputNumber address to t2
    li   $t8, 1                      # start our counter
    li   $a0, 0                      # output number
    j    hexaStringToDecimalLoop

hexaStringToDecimalLoop:
    lb   $t7, 0($t2)
    ble  $t7, '9', inputSub48       # if t7 less than or equal to char '9' inputSub48
    addi $t7, $t7, -55              # convert from string (ABCDEF) to int
    j    inputHexaNormalized
inputHexaNormalized:
    blt  $t7, $zero, convertFinish  # print int if t7 < 0
    li   $t6, 16                    # load 16 to t6
    mul  $a0, $a0, $t6              # t8 = t8 * t6
    add  $a0, $a0, $t7              # add t7 to a0
    addi $t2, $t2, 1                # increment array position
    j    hexaStringToDecimalLoop

inputSub48:
    addi $t7, $t7, -48              # convert from string (ABCDEF) to int
    j    inputHexaNormalized
```

So in the end I will have the decimal number stored in $a0.

The trick was to check if the number has ABCEDF chars and sum -55 in this case, otherwise -48.

Example:

```
'9' -48 = 9     #  '9' char to 9 int
'A' -55 = 10    #  'A' char to 10 int
```

Thanks to @wallyk. I started to write it again in python then converted to MIPS.